# Dockerizing kafka gives non zero exit code

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am a newbie trying to learn docker. I am trying to dockerize kafka installation and stuck with a non zero exit code. I would like to debug the issue and find out the reason. How to debug a docker file.

I tried executing the dockerd in debug mode by using `dockerd -D`.But this did not give any detailed logging.

I am running my script inside a vagrant dev box. Is there any way i can execute the build in debug mode.

Below is my docker file.

```
FROM library/ubuntu
RUN \
  cd /tmp &&\
  apt-get -y update && \
  apt-get -y install default-jre && \
  apt-get -y install zookeeperd && \
  apt-get -y install wget && \
  wget "http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache/kafka/0.8.2.1/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1.tgz" -O kafka.tgz && \
  mkdir -p ~/kafka && cd ~/kafka && \
  tar -xvzf /tmp/kafka.tgz --strip 1 && \

CMD ["nohup","/tmp/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh","/tmp/kafka/config/server.properties",">","/tmp/kafka/kafka.log","2>&1","&"]

EXPOSE 9092
```

Log:

```
root@devenv:/home/vagrant/sample_kafka# docker build -f Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM library/ubuntu
 ---> 20c44cd7596f
Step 2/3 : RUN cd /tmp &&  apt-get update &&   apt-get install default-jre &&   apt-get install zookeeperd &&   wget "http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache/kafka/0.8.2.1/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1.tgz" -O kafka.tgz &&   mkdir -p ~/kafka && cd ~/kafka &&   tar -xvzf /tmp/kafka.tgz --strip 1 && CMD ["nohup","/tmp/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh","/tmp/kafka/config/server.properties",">","/tmp/kafka/kafka.log","2>&1","&"]
 ---> Running in 0334e6d31438
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Sources [52.0 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [489 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [12.9 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [224 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3479 B]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Sources [9802 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1558 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [14.1 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [9827 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Sources [227 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [851 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [13.7 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [706 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [18.5 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [5174 B]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [6354 B]
Fetched 24.5 MB in 29s (837 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates ca-certificates-java dbus default-jre-headless fontconfig
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core fonts-dejavu-extra hicolor-icon-theme
  java-common krb5-locales libasound2 libasound2-data libasyncns0 libatk1.0-0
  libatk1.0-data libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3
  libbsd0 libcairo2 libcap-ng0 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdbus-1-3 libdrm-amdgpu1
  libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libedit2 libelf1
  libexpat1 libffi6 libflac8 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgif7 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
  libglapi-mesa libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-data libgmp10 libgnutls30
  libgraphite2-3 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common
  libharfbuzz0b libhogweed4 libicu55 libidn11 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8
  libjson-c2 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 liblcms2-2
  libllvm4.0 libnettle6 libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-nssdb libogg0 libp11-kit0
  libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpciaccess0
  libpcsclite1 libpixman-1-0 libpng12-0 libpulse0 libsensors4 libsndfile1
  libsqlite3-0 libssl1.0.0 libtasn1-6 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5
  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libwrap0 libx11-6 libx11-data
  libx11-xcb1 libxau6 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0
  libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1
  libxdamage1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxml2
  libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxtst6 libxxf86vm1 openjdk-8-jre
  openjdk-8-jre-headless openssl sgml-base shared-mime-info tcpd ucf
  x11-common xdg-user-dirs xml-core
Suggested packages:
  dbus-user-session | dbus-x11 default-java-plugin libasound2-plugins
  alsa-utils cups-common gnutls-bin krb5-doc krb5-user librsvg2-common gvfs
  liblcms2-utils pciutils pcscd pulseaudio lm-sensors icedtea-8-plugin
  libnss-mdns fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei
  fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic sgml-base-doc debhelper
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates ca-certificates-java dbus default-jre default-jre-headless
  fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core fonts-dejavu-extra
  hicolor-icon-theme java-common krb5-locales libasound2 libasound2-data
  libasyncns0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data
  libavahi-common3 libbsd0 libcairo2 libcap-ng0 libcups2 libdatrie1
  libdbus-1-3 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1
  libdrm2 libedit2 libelf1 libexpat1 libffi6 libflac8 libfontconfig1
  libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgif7
  libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-data
  libgmp10 libgnutls30 libgraphite2-3 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgtk2.0-0
  libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libharfbuzz0b libhogweed4 libicu55 libidn11
  libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libjson-c2 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1
  libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 liblcms2-2 libllvm4.0 libnettle6 libnspr4 libnss3
  libnss3-nssdb libogg0 libp11-kit0 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0
  libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpciaccess0 libpcsclite1 libpixman-1-0 libpng12-0
  libpulse0 libsensors4 libsndfile1 libsqlite3-0 libssl1.0.0 libtasn1-6
  libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2
  libwrap0 libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-xcb1 libxau6 libxcb-dri2-0
  libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0
  libxcb-sync1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp6
  libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxml2 libxrandr2 libxrender1
  libxshmfence1 libxtst6 libxxf86vm1 openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
  openssl sgml-base shared-mime-info tcpd ucf x11-common xdg-user-dirs
  xml-core
0 upgraded, 129 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 70.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 369 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    /bin/sh: 1: CMD: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /tmp &&  apt-get -y update &&   apt-get -y install default-jre &&   apt-get -y install zookeeperd &&   apt-get -y install wget &&   wget "http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache/kafka/0.8.2.1/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1.tgz" -O kafka.tgz &&   mkdir -p ~/kafka && cd ~/kafka &&   tar -xvzf /tmp/kafka.tgz --strip 1 && CMD ["nohup","/tmp/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh","/tmp/kafka/config/server.properties",">","/tmp/kafka/kafka.log","2>&1","&"]' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: Your `apt-get install` commands should use `-y` to always answer yes.

Comment: Can't background the main container process either. `nohup` and log redirection is not required.

Comment: @fiskeben you need to remove the last "&& \" from the RUN command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `apt-get install -y` so there are no user prompts.

The `CMD` will need to run in the foreground as well and doesn't need to use a log file. Docker has a stdout/stderr logging interface accessible with `docker logs CONTAINER`.

```
FROM library/ubuntu
RUN set -uex; \
    cd /tmp; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y default-jre zookeeperd; \
    wget "http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache/kafka/0.8.2.1/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1.tgz" -O kafka.tgz; \
    mkdir -p ~/kafka; \
    cd ~/kafka; \
    tar -xvzf /tmp/kafka.tgz --strip 1;

CMD ["/tmp/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh","/tmp/kafka/config/server.properties"]

EXPOSE 9092
```

I have a Debian based [kafka image on github](https://github.com/deployable/docker-kafka-zookeeper/blob/b007ca318131ed43b76c65220adc36a9305c8e96/Dockerfile) that includes a bit more detailed setup.

Comment: Hi Matt, I am getting the following error /bin/sh: 1: CMD: not found

Comment: Do you have a backslash on the final line of the `RUN` script?